# Why SHA hash generated from Angular application and online tool differs for unicode character

Tags: javascript, angular, unicode, sha256

The hash generated for text containing rupees symbol and unicode is always producing same hash if I execute in angular application where as it differs from the online hash generation tool
**Application**

₹  -  `sha256('₹')` => d8c3e87cd7f5b7d388f9dc1e35ccee09640ef3dca63d449d9ef59fc323a87a20

\u20B9 - `sha256('\u20B9')` = > d8c3e87cd7f5b7d388f9dc1e35ccee09640ef3dca63d449d9ef59fc323a87a20

**SHA256 online hash**

https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html gives different outputs

₹  - d8c3e87cd7f5b7d388f9dc1e35ccee09640ef3dca63d449d9ef59fc323a87a20

\u20B9 - 0d5f2a869bcab0dd97ef3aefca2dc44edeb55d71a5e78a026aad412c0bbaa55c

The library which is used for hash generation [js-sha256](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the online SHA256 hash tool you are using doesn't support Unicode character escape sequences. So when you tell it to compute the hash of `\u20B9` it doesn't pick up that you mean the rupee symbol and instead computes the hash of the six-character string with characters `\`, `u`, `2`, `0`, `B` and `9`. The SHA256 hash of this string is indeed `0d5f2a869bcab0dd97ef3aefca2dc44edeb55d71a5e78a026aad412c0bbaa55c`.

JavaScript supports Unicode character escapes, so in JavaScript, `'\u20B9'` and `'₹'` are the same string: they both represent a 1-character string containing only the rupee symbol. JavaScript supports other string escape sequences, for example `\n` represents a newline rather than a `\` followed by a `n`. See [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences) for a list of all JavaScript string escape sequences.

The online hash tool and the hashing library you are using both seem to be working correctly, the problem here seems to be your understanding of what is going on.

Comment: The online hash tool is the demo url mentioned in the same SHA library

Comment: The hash generated from JAVA side is coming as the hash generated for 6-characters. Therefore Hash on JavaScript is not matching with the server side hash. Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: @suneesh: without any code that demonstrates how you are calculating the SHA256 hash in Java, no.  I've just had a quick play with the Java `MessageDigest` class and it calculated the correct SHA-256 hash for a string containing only the rupee symbol. If you're getting the hash for the six characters, the string you are passing in must be the six-character string.

Comment: Found the issue. Angular httpClient by default treating responseType as json so the rupees symbol character itself is getting hashed whereas in java Unicode conversion happening while UTF-8 byte array and thus hashing occurs for \u20B9. Changing the response Type as 'text' in http request resolved this issue. The \u20B9 is treated as text and hash generated for the same.